# Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Why am I getting this error?

> Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
>   application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks
>   in the componentWillUnmount method.

**postAction.js**

```
export const getPosts = () => db.ref('posts').once('value');
```

**components:**

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { posts: null };
}

componentDidMount() {
  getPosts()
    .then(snapshot => {
      const result = snapshot.val();
      this.setState(() => ({ posts: result }));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.setState({ posts: null });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <PostList posts={this.state.posts} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: unmounted component dont have state, no need to do that. React is already telling you this is a `no-op`

Comment: You should not call `this.setState` in `componentWillUnmount`. Does the warning disappear if you remove that?

Comment: Hey you can read react lifecycle hooks docs on official website. It says when component is unmounting, no sort of state updation is done because ultimately that component's UI is being destroyed

Comment: getPosts() is asynchronous method. That's the mistake. Thank you all. Thank you @nicolas-tower

Answer (score 7):

As others mentioned, the setState in componentWillUnmount is unnecessary, but it should not be causing the error you're seeing. Instead, the likely culprit for that is this code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  getPosts()
    .then(snapshot => {
      const result = snapshot.val();
      this.setState(() => ({ posts: result }));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

since getPosts() is asynchronous, it's possible that before it can resolve, the component has unmounted. You're not checking for this, and so the .then can end up running after the component has unmounted.

To handle that, you can set a flag in willUnmount, and check for that flag in the .then:

```
componentDidMount() {
  getPosts()
    .then(snapshot => {
      if (this.isUnmounted) {
        return;
      }
      const result = snapshot.val();
      this.setState(() => ({ posts: result }));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.isUnmounted = true;
}
```

Comment: I don't get why this solution is so prevalent. This would just have the code fail (i.e. show no results) silently and get rid of the warning.

Comment: @milosa The fact that the component has unmounted means a parent component has decided that the results should no longer be shown. Therefore, silently showing no results is the expected behavior in most cases. If your needs differ, you can of course do a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.setState({ posts: null });
}
```

it's useless

From the doc:

> You should not call setState() in componentWillUnmount() because the
>   component will never be re-rendered. Once a component instance is
>   unmounted, it will never be mounted again.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount

Answer (score 0):

React component's state is a local entity. Unmounted component dont have state, no need to do that. React is already telling you this is a `no-op` which means no-operation in tech speak. It means that you telling component to do something when its already destroyed.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount

> You should not call setState() in componentWillUnmount() because the component will never be re-rendered. Once a component instance is unmounted, it will never be mounted again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { posts: null };
}

_isMounted = false;
componentDidMount() {
  this._isMounted = true;
  getPosts()
    .then(snapshot => {
      const result = snapshot.val();
      if(this._isMounted) { 
          this.setState(() => ({ posts: result }))
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this._isMounted = false;
  this.setState({ posts: null });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <PostList posts={this.state.posts} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

By using _isMounted, setState is called only if the component is mounted. the answer simply does a check to see if the component is mounted before setting the state.