# Does anyone have this issue? "To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method"

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

I run into a following message while implementing react application. Does anyone have same issue like this?

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.     in ProductList (at App.js:44)

My entry page is ProductList component. After loading entry page, if I click the LogOut in the header, I run into that message. Does anyone have some advice for it?

So I referred to several answers for it like

[Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51246815/cant-call-setstate-or-forceupdate-on-an-unmounted-component-this-is-a-no-op)

However I can't solve it, why this happens. :(

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Header from "./Header";
import ProductList from "./ProductList";
import Login from "./Login";
import Logout from "./Logout";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      query: "",
      isLoggedIn: false
    };
    this.handleLoginStatus = this.handleLoginStatus.bind(this);
    this.handleLogoutStatus = this.handleLogoutStatus.bind(this);
    this.setSearchKeyword = this.setSearchKeyword.bind(this);
  }

  handleLoginStatus() {
    this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
  }

  handleLogoutStatus() {
    this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false });
  }

  setSearchKeyword(query) {
    this.setState({
      query: query
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header setSearchKeyword={this.setSearchKeyword} />
        <Route
          path="/"
          exact={true}
          render={() => (
            <ProductList
              query={this.state.query}
              isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/login"
          render={() => (
            <Login
              isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn}
              handleLoginStatus={this.handleLoginStatus}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/logout"
          render={() => (
            <Logout
              isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn}
              handleLogoutStatus={this.handleLogoutStatus}
            />
          )}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

ProductList.js

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";

import axios from "axios";

class ProductList extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: null,
      loaded: false
    };
  }

  // componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  //   console.log(nextProps.query);
  // }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const url =
      "https://localhost/product/search?query=" + this.props.query;

    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("auth-token")
      },
      url
    };

    axios(options)
      .then(response => {
        let products = response.data;
        this.setState({ products: products });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("axios error", error);
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url =
      "https://localhost/product/search?query=" + this.props.query;

    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("auth-token")
      },
      url
    };

    axios(options)
      .then(response => {
        let products = response.data;
        this.setState({ products: products, loaded: true });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("axios error", error);
      });
  }

  // ComponentWillUnmount() {
  //   this.isUnmounted = true;
  // }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loaded) {
      let columnNames = ["Num", "Name", "Indications", "features"];
      let fieldNames = ["num", "name", "indications", "features"];

      var tableHeaders = (
        <tr>
          {columnNames.map(column => {
            return <th key={column}>{column}</th>;
          })}
        </tr>
      );

      var tableBody = this.state.products.map((product, i) => {
        return (
          <tr key={product + "_" + i}>
            {fieldNames.map((field, j) => {
              if (j === 0) {
                return <td key={product.name + "_" + i + "_" + j}>{i + 1}</td>;
              } else {
                return (
                  <td key={product.name + "_" + i + "_" + j}>{product[field]}</td>
                );
              }
            })}
          </tr>
        );
      });
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
          <thead>{tableHeaders}</thead>
          <tbody>{tableBody}</tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductList;
```

If you give some advice, it will be great help.

Comment: Your `<Route/>` component handles the mounting and unmounting of your components and when you attempt to logout  (meaning force `<Route/>` component to unmount `<ProductList />` or whatever component which will cause componentWillUnmount to be invoked ) your `axios` call gets interrupted and you have the above result. To fix you should exactly do what the warning message says : [cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation)

Comment: this (though a bit old) is also related: https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I will read them carefully.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is inside `componentDidUpdate` and because `this.setState` is asynchronous action an error shows up.

How does it happen?

1. Logout action happens
2. ProductList `componentDidUpdate` is not guarded by any condition and `this.setState` being called infinitely.
3. ProductList `componentWillUnmount` triggers
4. Asynchronous `this.setState({ products: products })` action from `componentDidUpdate` tries to update state
5. An error shows up

To fix your problem add a condition inside `componentDidUpdate`.

Official docs [about componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note
>   that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or
>   you’ll cause an infinite loop. It would also cause an extra
>   re-rendering which, while not visible to the user, can affect the
>   component performance. If you’re trying to “mirror” some state to a
>   prop coming from above, consider using the prop directly instead. Read
>   more about why copying props into state causes bugs.

**Example solution:**

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
   // Please do not forget to compare props
   if (this.props.somethingChanged !== prevProps.somethingChanged) {
     // this.setState logic here
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I solved this issue properly now, one thing I do not understand is that why step 2 (ProductList componentDidUpdate triggers) happens even when I click logout (I get out of ProductList). If it is possible, I would like to ask :)

Comment: Hi @AnnaLee thanks for asking and pointing that out. Actually `componentDidUpdate` is never being called! I've updated my answer. Please if my answer helped you marked it as "answered" so the others can see it. Good luck coding! :)

Comment: Thank you @loelsonk, it helps a lot. I will do.